# Email Template :: Merge Fields

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, leads, web2lead

I have an email template that sends an email on the creation of a new lead using web-to-lead.

[image]

When used in a flow I get the following error.

[image]

Has anyone had this issue before? I cannot get any fields from the lead record onto the email template.

I've tried using **{{{Lead.fieldName}}}** but that also throws a similar error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that Lead and Contact merge fields in Lightning Email templates are not compatible with Email Alerts. I think this is because Lightning templates use "Recipient" to represent both Leads and Contacts, so the email alert cannot resolve were to pull the data from.

For now, if you need to send an email alert with merge fields for a Lead or Contact record, you'll have to set it up with a Classic Email Template.